# how to convert html theme to magento theme?

Tags: magento, themes, magento-1.9

I have a theme folder where there are only php, html, css and js file are contained. I want to convert my current theme using those css files. Please tell me the steps to do that.

Comment: For that you need to understand the structure of magento and use designer guide for magento documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A Magento theme is comprised of templating files (layout, template, locale) and/or skin files (CSS, images, theme-specific JavaScript) that create the visual experience of your store. These files reside in two main directories in your Magento file system:

• “app/design” directory – Files that control how the page templates are rendered

• “skin” directory – Files that control the visual aspects of the theme—CSS, images, etc

More Info [link](http://www.magenmarket.com/news-and-blog/how-to-create-a-custom-theme-in-magento.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the theme for Magento then follow the steps:

Your theme can have these folders,

[image]

The theme contains the folders, Not necessarily "js" and "media" folders. You have to place the right folders and files to the right place.That's it.

1. So first, open the "app" folder of your own theme and side by side open "app" folder of installed Magento. If your own theme is not an independent "package" then paste **"app\design\frontend\default\your_theme"** to the Magento **"app\design\frontend\default"** or **"app\design\frontend\rwd"** based on which package your theme is using.

**Note: Here "default" and "rwd" are package names.**

So, If your own theme is an independent package then no need to paste it within a package just copy **"app\design\frontend\your_theme"** to **"app\design\frontend"**

2. Now do same for the "skin" folder. Paste your theme **"skin\frontend\default\your_theme"** to the **"skin\frontend\default"** folder of Magento.

**Note** that if your theme is an independent package then copy **"skin\frontend\your_theme"** and paste it in **"skin\frontend"** folder of Magento installation folder.

3. Now for the remaining **"js"** and **"media"** folders, just copy and paste the files or folders of your theme to **"js"** and **"media"** folders of Magento installation.

**Short explanation:** In Magento normal theme package there are phtml,xml,css,js,images. phtml and xml goes to app\design\frontend\ and css,js, images goes to skin\frontend.

4. In advance, if your theme package have some extension included with it then there maybe a "code" and an "etc" folder inside of "app" folder. And that contain .php and .xml files. So for that copy **"app\etc\modules\your_theme's_xml_files"** to **"app\etc\modules"** file of Magento installation.

Now go to **"app\code\community"** and/or **"app\code\local"** and copy all the folders of your theme folder. Then go to the same "community" or "local" folders of Magento installation "app\code" and paste the folders.

Comment: i have not downloaded magento theme so i don't have app/design/frontend folders. I have only .html files, .css files and .js files are there in the respective folders. how can I apply that style in may admin panel?